# Implementing "Invite Friends" feature?

Tags: java, database, playframework, backend

- I am using `Play Framework` and want to implement `"Invite Friends"` feature when user signs up. How do I implement that?
- for example two users `A` & `B` invite their `mutual friend C`, now C joins with the invitation of A, how do I know at the backed that it has to be associated to A and `NOT` B when he joins the application?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with `Play Framework` but try sending an unique ID in each invitation. Then when 'C' joins, you check which ID he followed onto joining. That way you can credit the person with whom that ID was associated.

Comment: Irrespective of the framework , this is nice and simple. Also, if user A has shared a doc and C has not joined the app, but C registers, then C must be associated to A directly, right, does the same rule of association applies here as well?

Comment: Yes, you can also use this principle here. That way whenever C gets in contact with your app (joining, registering or even just viewing) you can check who lead him there.